# I can't find where is wrong of my GLSL code?

Tags: swift, opengl-es

I am an iOS developer, use *Xcode* to compile some *GLSL* code. The `shaderv.vsh` code likes below:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 positionColor;
attribute vec2 textCoordinate;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
varying lowp vec2 varyTextCoord;
varying lowp vec4 varyColor;

void main() {
    varyTextCoord = textCoordinate;
    varyColor = positionColor;

    vec4 vPos;
    vPos = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * position;
    gl_Position = vPos;
}
```

And the `shaderf.fsh` code likes below:

```
precision lowp float;

varying lowp vec2 varyTextCoord;
varying lowp vec4 varyColor;
uniform sampler2D colorMap;

void main() {
    vec4 cs = texture2D(colorMap,varyTextCoord);
    vec4 cd = varyColor;
    float s = 0.2;
    float d = 0.5;
    vec4 color = (cs * s) + (cd * d);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

When compile this code, it will be come into some error:

```
ERROR: 0:15: 'premature EOF' : syntax error syntax error

ERROR: 0:5: 'premature EOF' : syntax error syntax error
```

I can't find where is wrong. It has troubled me for a long time. Help me!

Comment: Probably the shader files are not read. Possibly the path respectively working directory is wrong.

Comment: The same swift code, I can compile another shader code rightly.@Rabbid76

Comment: The error message is *"premature EOF"*. That is not an error message which is caused by the code.

Comment: This is my [swift code](https://github.com/dowZhang/dowImageView/blob/master/DowImageView).Can you  help me.@Rabbid76

Comment: Th issue is not the code. The issue is that the shader files are not read respectively found. Try to print or dump the shader code.

Comment: @Rabbid76 You are right. I can't read *shader* code correctly because of I didn't convert *shader string* to cString. I have answered this question.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. My *shader* code is right. One *swift* function I used by mistake.

```
let content = try? String(contentsOfFile: file, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
var source = UnsafePointer<GLchar>(content)
shader = glCreateShader(type)

glShaderSource(shader, 1,&source, nil)
```

When compile *shader* string I should convert it to cString.

```
let content = try? String(contentsOfFile: file, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
let contentCString = content?.cString(using: .utf8)
var source = UnsafePointer<GLchar>(contentCString)
```

Thanks to everyone hinted me.